# unit test of function in different directory gives AttributeError: module has no attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

What specific syntax must be changed below in order for a unit test running in one part of a file system to successfully test a function in a class that is located in a completely different part of a file system?

The test file is located at `C:\path\to\some-test-classes\test_an_example.py`

The class being tested is located at `C:\\completely\\different\\path\\an_example.py`

The problem might be in the structure of `C:\\completely\\different\\path\\an_example.py`, because the `C:\\completely\\different\\path\\an_example.py` IS being imported into `C:\path\to\some-test-classes\test_an_example.py` as shown below.

Here are the details:

**TEST FILE:**

The test file located at `C:\path\to\some-test-classes\test_an_example.py` is:

```
import unittest
import subprocess

#Run the tests in this file by running the following command in the terminal:
#python -m unittest test_an_example.py

class TestCommandBuilder(unittest.TestCase):

  def test_someMethod(self):
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(0, 'C:\\completely\\different\\path\\')
    print('sys.path is: ', str(sys.path))
    import an_example
    print('90909090')
    firstString = "hello"
    secondString = ' there'
    returnBool = an_example.someMethod(firstString, secondString)
    self.assertTrue(returnBool)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**CLASS BEING TESTED:**

The class being tested is located at `C:\\completely\\different\\path\\an_example.py` and contains the following:

```
class an_example:

  def __init__(self):  
    pass

  def someMethod(firstString, secondString):
    print("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^")
    print("firstString is: ",firstString)
    print("secondString is: ",secondString)
    combinedString = firstString+secondString
    print("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^")
    if combinedString == "hello there":
      return True
    else: 
      return False
```

**CURRENT ERROR:**

Currently, the following error is being returned:

```
C:\path\to\some-test-classes>python -m unittest test_an_example.py
sys.path is:  ['C:\\completely\\different\\path\\', 'C:\\path\\to\\some-test-classes', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages']
90909090
E
 ======================================================================  
ERROR: test_someMethod (test_an_example.TestCommandBuilder)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path\to\some-test-classes\test_an_example.py", line 62, in test_someMethod
    returnBool = an_example.someMethod(firstString, secondString)
AttributeError: module 'an_example' has no attribute 'someMethod'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.006s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

As you can see from the results of the `print(...)` commands in the above, the class `an_example` IS being loaded into `test_an_example.py`, but the `someMethod(firstString, secondString)` member of the `an_example` class is NOT being found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine. The issue is that you never import the `an_example` class. In your test file you import `an_example` but you are importing the module. You can actually see it in the traceback:

> AttributeError: **module** 'an_example' has no attribute 'someMethod'

In order to import the class `an_example` you would need to do something like this:

```
  def test_someMethod(self):
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(0, 'C:\\completely\\different\\path\\')
    print('sys.path is: ', str(sys.path))

    # import an_example  # remove this

    from an_example import an_example        # changed this

    print('90909090')
    firstString = "hello"
    secondString = ' there'
    returnBool = an_example.someMethod(firstString, secondString)
    self.assertTrue(returnBool)
```